# Получить значение по ключу

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Имеются 3 таблицы: `Stations, Net, Networkstations`. Таблицы `Stations` и `Net` связаны с таблицей `Networkstations` связью "один ко многим". Как получить список состоящий из `name` из таблицы `Net` с помощью `idnet` из `Networkstations`? Иными словами как с помощью ключей получить значения?  Если я правильно понял связанные поля поля можно получить с помощью `select_related`, однако когда я вывожу их представлении, не могу найти связанные поля, вместо этого я также вижу список Id(смотрите рисунок)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**models.py:**

```
class Networkstations(models.Model):
    idnet = models.ForeignKey(Net, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='IdNet', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    idstation = models.ForeignKey('Station', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='IdStation', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'networkstations'

class Net(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'net'

class Station(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sitecode = models.CharField(db_column='SiteCode', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    latitude = models.DecimalField(db_column='Latitude', max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    longitude = models.DecimalField(db_column='Longitude', max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    link = models.CharField(db_column='Link', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'station'
```

**views.py:**

```
class List(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'station_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        name = serializers.serialize('json',Networkstations.objects.select_related('idnet'))
        ctx = {
            'name':name,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
net_names = Net.objects.filter(networkstations__idnet=...).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Или так (не уверен, нужно пробовать)

```
networkstation = Networkstations.objects.get(idnet=...)
net_names = networkstation.net_set.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
```